# Can I send DescribeUserPoolClient commands for a user pool in another AWS account

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

looking for some AWS Javascript SDK help.

I am in the situation that my User Pool is defined in a separate account to my Lambda which needs to send a DescribeUserPoolClient command.

Code snippet below:

```js
import {
  CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
  DescribeUserPoolClientCommand,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider';

export async function describeUserPoolClient(userPoolClientId: string, userPoolId: string) {
  const cognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({});
  const describeUserPoolClientCommand = new DescribeUserPoolClientCommand({
    ClientId: userPoolClientId,
    UserPoolId: userPoolId,
  });

  const userPoolClient = await cognitoClient.send(describeUserPoolClientCommand);
  return userPoolClient;
}
```

Since I can only provide a `userPoolId` and not a full ARN, I can't see a way to send this request cross-account without assuming a role in the other account which makes my local testing a nightmare with getting roles and policies set up.

Can anyone see another way of doing this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Toby, did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Sten, unfortunately the only way to do this is to create a role with DescribeUserPoolCient permissions in the other account and grant assume role access to the role in your current account. Then you assume that role in your current account and use those credentials to send the DescribeUserPoolClient command